# how to access multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var x = [{firstlevel: [{
        secondlevel: [{
            'fname': 'harsh',
            'lname': 'gupta'
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I want to access secondlevel array without loop-in. Is there a way to directly access the secondlevel array?

I could access it with .map()

```
x.map(function(item, index) {
   return item.firstlevel[index].secondlevel[index]
})
```

but still finding a better approach.

Comment: You have to map through one and then the other. The outer array could be bigger than a child and vice versa

Comment: In this particular instance, `var secondLevel = x[0].firstlevel[0].secondlevel;`. If the first and second level arrays can be of any size, then your `map()` solution seems pretty solid to me.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ magic numbers is rarely ever the answer

Comment: @Harsh, It's hard to know how to help with this because the example is too vague. Is that array `x` going to have many items all with `firstlevel` properties?  Is the `firstlevel` array going to have many items? With all those items have `secondlevel` or something else. Please give a more complete example.

Comment: The *map* solution is pretty wasteful. `x[0].firstlevel[0].secondlevel` gives you direct access to the array of objects, using *map* just makes another array of the same objects, you might as well do `x[0].firstlevel[0].secondlevel.splice()` and save the iterations. Also, the way you're using *item* means you'll get `firstlevel[0].secondlevel[0]`, then `firstlevel[1].secondlevel[1]`, etc. so a kind of diagonal filter.

Comment: @Mark_M `firstlevel[]` array will contain only `secondlevel[]` array. Both array's **.length** will always be 1.

Comment: @HarshGupta—in that case, *map* is completely unnecessary and *index* will always be zero (0).

Answer (score 1):

Without loop in, this is the only solution:

```
var arr = x[0].firstlevel[0].secondlevel
```